# Cocoa: Parse NSString by character length

Tags: cocoa, parsing, nsstring, nsarray

I have an NSString I'm working with, but I would like to parse it by character length.  So break it apart into an NSArray, and have each object in the array be x characters from that string.  So basically, break up the string into sub strings of a certain length

So, how do I do it?

example:

NSString  *string = @"Here is my string"

NSArray objects:

"Her"

"e i"

"s m"

"y s"

"tri"

"ng"

Comment: I think you need to describe better what you're trying to do.  You want to break up the string into substrings of a certain length?

Comment: Show an example string in your question, and how you want it broken up. It will give us a better idea.

Comment: there you go!  Hopefully it's clear enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can this work? Not tested though

```
@interface NSString (MyStringExtensions)
- (NSArray*)splitIntoPartsWithLength:(NSUInteger)length;
@end

@implementation NSString (MyStringExtensions)
- (NSArray*)splitIntoPartsWithLength:(NSUInteger)length
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger count = [self length];

    while (length > 0) {
        if (range.location+length >= count) {
            [array addObject:[self substringFromIndex:range.location]];
            return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
        }
        [array addObject:[self substringWithRange:range]];
        range.location = range.location + length;
    }
    return nil;
} 
@end
```

**EDIT** -- implemented as a category use as

```
NSString *myString = @"Wish you a merry x-mas";
NSArray *array = [myString splitIntoPartsWithLength:10];
```

Comment: so this will let me parse the string into pieces x characters long?
What do I do, just modify the int length to the length I want?

Comment: It's a method, so you would specify the length when sending yourself this `splitString:intoPartLengths:` message.

Comment: epatel: You never decrease the value of `length`, so that `while` loop will loop forever.

Comment: Peter: He'll get into the if statement eventually and exit the while loop there. I don't find it the easiest to follow code, but it should work.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting there, but I'm getting the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd21920" when I run it

Comment: matt: Did you add the method to the class that that instance is an instance of? You need to do that.

Comment: yea.  I'm calling it with 

[array splitString:string intoPartLengths:10];

(array and string are created earlier in my code)